# Sync Framework 2.1 Socket forbidden

Tags: c#, sockets, microsoft-sync-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Sync Framework 2.1 in Windows 8.1 (C#,XAML). I am using SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2. I configured Sync in server and client app.

But while trying to do sync, I am getting following error.

```
var offlineContext = new DefaultScopeOfflineContext(DatabaseName, new Uri(SyncServerUri, UriKind.Absolute));
await offlineContext.SynchronizeAsync();
```

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Error code : 10013

When I keep fiddler open, I dont see this error. Otherwise I am getting this error. I tried disabling anti virus software in server and added inbound rule to allow port 80 through firewall. Nothing works.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve it by myself. In Windows 8.1 application, the option Private Network (Client and server) must be checked in the package manifest file. That is it. !!!

[image: Screenshot of package manifest]